# Explain abbreviations used by users briefly

Tags: discussion, faq

I've seen many users using abbreviations in their answers like

> sarva-rūpe āsvādaye kṛṣṇa-sevānanda 
>  sei balarāma — gaura-saṅge
>   nityānanda [CC - 1.5.11]

So here, please explain what does `CC - 1.5.11` mean, also this is not the only one, I've seen many others like `HP`, `SG`, `BG` etc.

If you can, define what does each term means, in brief and what are those numbers followed after a `-`

I am asking this question because am seeing many users getting confused with the terms, for example

> what's the meaning of [BG - 12.5] and other notations? –  [user13107](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2318/why-does-hindus-worship-different-gods-if-they-believe-in-only-one-god-which-is/2328#comment3643_2328)

<sup>Note : This question will act as a reference, so please answer in detail</sup>

Comment: I had thought to add in my profile about page the list of abbreviations I use, but it seemed big. Now I will add it here and provide reference if anyone asks in the future.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Below are the full form of the abbreviations I have used so far:

- BG - Bhāgavad Gitā
- SB - Śrimad Bhāgavatam
- MB - Mahābhārata
- RCM - Rāmcharitmānas
- VRM - Vālmiki Rāmāyan
- VP - Vishnu Purana
- BVP - Brahmavaivarta Purana
- HP - Harivamsa Purana
- GP - Garuda Purana
- AP - Agni Purana
- PP - Padma Purana
- LP - Linga Purana
- DB - Devi Bhagavata
- Sve. Up -Svetasvatara Upanishad
- Mait. Up - Maitrayaniya Upanishad
- Chg. Up - Chandogya Upanishad
- Tait. Up - Taitariya Upanishad
- Mund. Up - Mundaka Upanishad
- Mand. Up. - Mandukya Upanishad
- Brh. Up - Bṛhadāraṇyaka Upanishad
- Manu - Manu Smriti
- Brh. Su. - Brahma Sutra
- CC - Chaitanya Charitamruta

All these texts contain chapters and some also like Shrimad Bhagavatam contain sub chapters. So the number besides them imply the verse number in chapter wise order. For example, `BG- 12.5` means 5th verse of the 12th chapter. `SB - 1.2.5` means, 5th verse of the second chapter that belongs to the first section of the book. If you browse the http://vedabase.com site, you will get an idea of how the verse numbering is used.